# How to create two different firewall rules with the same name that applies to different profiles using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, firewall, powershell

I have a server that has the following firewall rules.

[image]

I'd like to mimic this on a another server running the same OS. Currently, I have this rule.

[image]

How do I split it into two rules: one that is enabled for Public profile, and another that's disabled for Domain and Private profiles?